Efficiently counting the number of 2D points with higher coordinates in both X and Y axes
I am a university student stuck on an assignment for my Advanced Algorithms class.
The task in simple terms:
I'm given an array of 2D points. For each point, I need to display the number of other points that have greater X and Y coordinates. For each point, the Y coordinate is unique.
The hint given for this assignment is "merge sort". After a bit of Googling I saw a few things about inversion counting, but I couldn't apply it to 2D points.
Instead, I built a different algorithm:
Merge sort by the y cooridnate. Each time an element is added during the merge, backtrack through the already added elements and increase the count for each one that has a lower x coordinate.
It works fine, it gives me the right output, but this backtracking method is quite inefficient, and takes too long as n gets large. It not much better than doing it with 2 nested loops. Unfortunately, this was the only thing I could think of that was built around a merge sort.
I'm looking for ideas that would speed up my code. Thanks in advance.
Here is my algorithm:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
    int count;
    int isAtRightSide; // Only used during mergeAndCount
} Point;

void mergeAndCount(Point *arr[], int l, int m, int r, int minXDiff) {
    int i, j, k;
    int n1 = m - l + 1;
    int n2 = r - m;

    Point *L[n1];
    Point *R[n2];

    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
        L[i] = arr[l + i];
        L[i]->isAtRightSide = 0;
    }

    for (j = 0; j < n2; j++) {
        R[j] = arr[m + 1 + j];
        R[j]->isAtRightSide = 1;
    }

    // ==========

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    k = l;

    while (i < n1 || j < n2) {
        if (i < n1 && j < n2) {
            if (L[i]->y <= R[j]->y) {
                arr[k] = L[i++];
            } else {
                arr[k] = R[j++];
            }
        } else if (i < n1) {
            arr[k] = L[i++];
        } else {
            arr[k] = R[j++];
        }

        for (int o = k - 1; o >= l; o--) {
            if (
                arr[o]->x + minXDiff <= arr[k]->x &&
                arr[o]->isAtRightSide != arr[k]->isAtRightSide // Same side already has it counted
            ) {
                arr[o]->count++;
            }
        }

        k++;
    }
}

void mergeSortAndCount(Point *arr[], int l, int r, int minXDiff) {
    if (l < r) {
        int m = l + (r - l) / 2;

        mergeSortAndCount(arr, l, m, minXDiff);
        mergeSortAndCount(arr, m + 1, r, minXDiff);

        mergeAndCount(arr, l, m, r, minXDiff);
    }
}

int main() {
    int n, minXDiff;

    scanf("%d %d", &n, &minXDiff);

    Point **points = malloc(n * sizeof(Point*));
    Point **temp = malloc(n * sizeof(Point*));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        points[i] = temp[i] = malloc(sizeof(Point));
        points[i]->count = 0;

        scanf("%d %d", &points[i]->x, &points[i]->y);
    }

    // ====================

    mergeSortAndCount(temp, 0, n - 1, minXDiff);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", points[i]->count);
    }

    // ====================

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        free(points[i]);
    }

    free(points);
    free(temp);

    return 0;
}

I'd also appreciate constructive criticism over what I made here.

IMHO basic sorting cannot work alone. I would personally use a k-d-tree or a quad-tree for that. You can easily track all the points in O(n log n) time with that (n is the number of output points). Maybe interval trees also work for this (probably more complex though).

@JérômeRichard No, sorting can work. M sophisticated data structures would be a lot more straightforward though.

@btilly By "work" I mean efficient (otherwise a naive loop does the job). Sorting is meant to compute a total order but there is no total order for this. This is why I do not expect sorting to be efficient. Maybe I missed a cleaver trick (hence the "alone") ;) .

I haven't thought it through completely, but my inclination is to create a hash-table keyed on the unique y in a struct with the no. of greater x, y values as members.As points are initially read, update the hash-table with the new y value and then iterate over the hash-table for all lesser values of y incrementing the greater x, y members. At least a hash type lookup and limit of updates per-addition to only lesser values of y would help keep the amount of work in check as the number of points grow. Understand, this is just a first-thought idea - you will have to determine any benefit.

@JérômeRichard I've already worked out a O(n log(n)) answer and have clarified the hint based on it. I'm saying that sorting can work because I know how to do it that way.

I would iterate by descending Y and use a Fenwick tree to count the preceding points with higher X.

@btilly I have to say I did not understand the answer.

@JérômeRichard Because this is homework, I deliberately left something for the student to do. But the answer is correct. If you first sort by y, then mergesort by x breaking ties in favor of the second list, you can do the bookkeeping to produce the answer in O(n log(n)) work.

@MattTimmermans I can think of several easy ways to do it if you have access to more sophisticated data structure. The challenge is how to do it with just an understanding of sorting algorithms, based on the given hint.

If you know how to count inversions, then consider this:  Sort by Y descending.  Now you want to resort by X ascending.  Inversions occur where x2 > x1, but y2 > y1.  These are exactly the cases you want to count.

@MattTimmermans Same initial thought here.

@MattTimmermans And that will lead to what I offered.

@btilly yes, it will.  OP is also not too far off the mark in the question. I think he's just missing the magic part about how to use the relationship between the two orderings.

Here is an explanation of the hint.
Sort by y first.
Mergesort by x, breaking ties by taking them from the second list. Every time you merge an element from the first list, what is the efficient way to find how many points you just found with higher x and y?
Note, the condition that y is distinct will matter.

This is not an appropriate answer because it is not an answer. Stack Overflow is a questions-and-answers site, not a homework-help site. It may help with homework, but that is an incidental consequence. Answering in hints is not suitable.

@EricPostpischil At what point short of a working solution in the preferred language does it stop being an answer? The questioner was stuck. The questioner should now be unstuck. Yes, I left a piece. I also believe that figuring out that O(1) line of code is a valuable learning experience.

I would argue that for homework questions, the unethical thing to do is provide the solution in code.  Writing text which explains some vague point and thus helps the OP get unstuck is fine.

Whether the explanation is useful or not, that's another question.

Re “At what point short of a working solution in the preferred language does it stop being an answer?”: It does not state an algorithm. Re “The questioner was stuck. The questioner should now be unstuck… valuable learning experience.”: As I wrote, Stack Overflow is not a tutorial or homework-help site. It is a question-and-answer site. Your questions speak to helping this one person. Stack Overflow is intended to be a durable repository for the future. People will come seeking solutions to problems, not just homework questions. This is not a proper answer for that.

@EricPostpischil that is what Stack Overflow could, ideally, be.  But established usage patterns show that this is not what it is. Can you point to a meta post where this is discussed and the official conclusion is that this what Stack Overflow is, and that every answer that does not go along with that deserves to be down-voted?

@MikeNakis: It is not a conclusion; it is the stated mission. Stack Overflow is about “getting answers” (bold in the original). Stack Overflow is not a community-operated site. It is the operation of a for-profit company that decide to use the community to create a database of questions-and-answers as a business model. Voting down “answers” that do not provide sufficient information is part of the general guidelines for voting down.

One way to achieve it is by understanding that it is enough for a solution to rely on results already seen during the iteration. Why? Because if we sort by Y and descend on these points, we are guaranteed no future point in the iteration can meet the expectation for the current point (no points have a greater Y ahead in the list).
Now the question becomes, from the Xs we have seen so far, how many are greater than the current one, which obliges some data structure to efficiently answer, as well as update as we go.
